# register environment variables on remote computers in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am just trying to learn powershell and through some examples I found came up with the following script.  I'm attempting to register some environment variables on the different servers.  When I run it I get the error -

```
Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At C:\Users\gswartz\Desktop\regvalue.ps1:3 char:16
+     Invoke-Command <<<<  -ComputerName $server [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("xxxx", "xxxx", "Machine")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Here's the script.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function set_vars($server) {

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("xxxx", "xxxx", "Machine")
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("xxxx", "xxxx", "Machine")
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("xxxx", "xxxx", "Machine")
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("xxxx", "xxxx", "Machine")

    Write-Host "vars set for $server"
}

$servers = @("server1","server2")

$servers | ForEach{ 
    set_vars $_ 
}
```

Comment: `{` and `}` are missing.

Comment: It would be recommended to use group policy to do this rather than a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock { ... }
```